# replace ruby code in all files with unix command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, unix

I have a string `!Rails.env.dev? || params['render_javascript']`.
I want to replace this string with `render_javascript`. It will be lots of work if I do it one file by one file.
I tried to use unix command as follows, but no luck.

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.rb")
do
       sed 's/!Rails\.env\.dev\? \|\| params\['render_javascript'\]/render_javascript/g' $i > x
       mv x $i
done
```

Anyone can offer me some help here?

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code/command. First, you are escaping characters unnecessarily. Second, if we use double quotes to quote sed command it will be better in this case. You can try below command:

```
for i in $(find . -name "*.rb")
do
    sed "s/\!Rails\.env\.dev? || params\['render_javascript'\]/render_javascript/g" $i > x 
    mv x $i
done
```

`sed` (`GNU sed`) uses `Basic Regular expression (BRE)` which does not have `?`, `|` metacharacters, so you do not have to escape them. Metacharacters `?`, `|` are added by `Extended Regular Expresson (ERE)`.

And, I have used double quotes `"` to quote the sed command, because there are single quotes `'` in your search regex. And because double quotes was used to quote the sed command, we also have to escape the `!` character. We have to escape `!` because it is a shell special character and expands to something else, even before sed command is run.

---

If you want to use `Extended regular expression (ERE)`, then you can use `-r` option with the `sed` command. In this case, you have escape `?` and `|` character. For example:

```
sed -r "s/\!Rails\.env\.dev\? \|\| params\['render_javascript'\]/render_javascript/g" $i > x
```

Comment: thank you. I ran above script, it works well but there's extra newline in the end of each file.

Comment: you mean that the script is adding an extra newline at the end of file? Is this happenning for all files? Or only with some files?

Comment: all files. I think unix think every file should end with new line char.

Comment: Still confused. You mean there is an extra line with just a new line character, i.e. A blank line at the end? Or , the last line (which is not blank) has a newline char at the end? This script will - presumably - not add a newline if it is not already there.